Console logs are not logging in Azure Kubernetes Cluster container insights for ASP.NET Core application
Added Serilog in the ASP.NET Core application:
Serilog.ILogger logger;
LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration();

logger = (Serilog.ILogger)loggerConfiguration
             .MinimumLevel.Verbose().Enrich.FromLogContext()
             // .WriteTo.Logger(appLog => appLog.Filter.ByExcluding(e => IsTraceLogEvent(e))
             .WriteTo.File(GetAbsoluteLogFilePath(Configuration.GetSection("Serilog:PathFormat").Value),
                              fileSizeLimitBytes: null,
                              rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                              // retainedFileTimeLimit: TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(Configuration.GetSection<string>("LogFileTimeLimit"))),
                              outputTemplate: Configuration.GetSection("Serilog:LogOutputTemplate").Value,
                              restrictedToMinimumLevel: (Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel), Configuration["Serilog:LogLevel"]))

             .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error)
             .CreateLogger();

These error logs should be logged in AKS container insights, but these logs are not logging as expected, can anybody suggest am I missing something?
.WriteTo.Console() will log errors in AKS container insights automatically, but not happening as expected.

check these out

Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core
Configure an ASP.NET Core app for Azure App Service (platform-windows)


Quick question on your environment as you did not mention: Is this a Linux or Windows environment? Windows has additional requirements to send SDTOUT to K8s, so trying to clarify...

To ensure that Serilog logs are captured and displayed in AKS container insights, you need to verify a few things.
Ensure Application Insights is configured

Ensure that AKS is correctly configured to send logs to Azure Monitor
az aks enable-addons --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <your-aks-cluster> --addons monitoring



Configure ASP.NET Core Application with Serilog
dotnet new webapi -n SerilogLoggingApp
cd SerilogLoggingApp

# Add Serilog packages
dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Console
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.File
dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights



Update Program.cs to configure Serilog
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using Serilog;

using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

  

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

  

// Configure Serilog

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()

.MinimumLevel.Verbose()

.Enrich.FromLogContext()

.WriteTo.Console()

.WriteTo.File("logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)

.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration { InstrumentationKey = "abcd-efgh-ijk-lmnop-cd31ad4d99d1" }, TelemetryConverter.Traces)

.CreateLogger();

  

builder.Host.UseSerilog(); // Add Serilog

  

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

  

var app = builder.Build();

  

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())

{

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI();

}

  

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

  

app.UseAuthorization();

  

app.MapControllers();

  

app.Run();

  

Log.CloseAndFlush(); // Ensure to close and flush the log


edit your Dockerfile accordingly,
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SerilogLoggingApp/SerilogLoggingApp.csproj", "SerilogLoggingApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SerilogLoggingApp/SerilogLoggingApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SerilogLoggingApp"
RUN dotnet build "SerilogLoggingApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SerilogLoggingApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SerilogLoggingApp.dll"]


and build and push it to your container registry
az acr login --name myACR
docker build -t myacr.azurecr.io/serilogloggingapp:latest .
docker push myacr.azurecr.io/serilogloggingapp:latest



Create a Kubernetes deployment and service YAML file for the same-
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serilogloggingapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serilogloggingapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serilogloggingapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: serilogloggingapp
        image: arkoacr.azurecr.io/serilogloggingapp:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serilogloggingapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: serilogloggingapp



Now you can verify your container logs
ContainerLog
| project LogEntry, TimeGenerated, ContainerID
| limit 50



Reference-

Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core
Configure an ASP.NET Core app for Azure App Service (platform-windows)
Similar SO thread

